# How can I modify the wtime of ext filesystem

Tags: filesystems, ext3, ext4, ext2

How can I modify the superblock of an ext filesystem so that I can set the field **wtime (Last write time)**?

I've tried with debugfs:

```
debugfs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
debugfs:  open /dev/sdd2 -w
debugfs:  ssv wtime "@0x64000000"
debugfs:  show_super_stats -h
debugfs:  close
```

When I close the filesystem **wtime** is set to the current system time.

Obviously I don't want to change the system time so that the **wtime** is set when the filesystem is closed and then to revert my system time.

My second thought was that I can change it with hexeditor, but I'm almost sure that the superblock has a checksum that is calculated over the superblock and verified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I've read the answer of Peter Horvath. I looked in the sources and as he pointed out [here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/lib/ext2fs/closefs.c#n302) `ext2fs_flush2` writes this field and the actual code is like so:

```
fs->super->s_wtime = fs->now ? fs->now : time(NULL);
```

I've searched the sources for this `fs->now` and found that it is being set by [`do_set_current_time`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/debugfs/debugfs.c#n1952). I thought I had tried this the last time, but I did try once more. And actually the following code did the job.

```
debugfs:  open /dev/sdb2 -w
debugfs:  ssv mtime "@0x64000000"
debugfs:  set_current_time "@0x64000000"
Setting current time to Thu Mar  2 01:46:40 2023

debugfs:  close
```

Edit: you should touch the superblock if you want `wtime` to get updated. And you can't set 0 as your **current_time**.

Answer (score 2):

Digging in the source code of our software isn't from the devil. I researched after them a little bit and found the following results:

1. Debugfs is in the package e2fsprogs.
2. E2fsprogs contains the libext2 library as well, which is the common library to handle all of the ext2 manipulation operations as well.
3. When we see the [source code of the e2fsprogs](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/), with some greps can we found very easily the point of the the [close_filesys](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/debugfs/debugfs.c#n215) command in it.
4. We can see, that this call calls always `ext2_close_free()`, which is already in the libext2fs source code, [here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/lib/ext2fs/closefs.c).
5. In the named function we can see the [updates of the wtime](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/lib/ext2fs/closefs.c#n302): `ext2fs_close_free()` calls `ext2fs_close2()`, which calls `ext2fs_close()`, which calls `ext2fs_flush2()`, which calls `ext2fs_flush()`.
6. As we can see in this function, the `wtime` field will be always updated. There is no exception.

But: you can easily disable that in the source code. If you come here again, I will explain you, how.

P.s. yes, there is a checksum in the ext2 superblock, and it is generated by crc32c which is a complex algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Well, *possibly* user-space is the solution, you can try fuse-ext2

Homepage: http://view-os.sourceforge.net